# Inserting Strings Without Trailing Spaces SQL

Tags: sql, spaces

I have a database with a field named Field1 that has 100 nchars per entry.
Each time I add a value, it is stored as:

```
"value     (100-ValueLength Spaces)        "
```

So Basically each stored value has a string of spaces after it.  This is getting to be an issue when I try doing:

```
if (value == "Example")
```

because of all of the empty spaces after the string. 
How can I get it so the stored values don't have all of these trailing spaces?

Comment: Not sure, although I think it is plain SQL
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 if that helps at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a variable-length string, use `nvarchar(100)` instead of `nchar(100)`. The later always has 100 characters, the former can have up to 100 characters, but doesn't fill up the space.

Comment: Got it.  When I started building my database, I didn't know the difference between nchar and nvarchar, and opted to use nchar, and now I realize the mistake I made.

Comment: Useful answer. When might someone want to use nchar over nvarchar?

Answer (score 3):

Use the sql `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` functions when inserting.

Comment: I'm using LINQ to insert, is there a LINQ equivalent to what you're talking about?

Comment: Then simply apply Trim to the string, there's no need to use sql functions in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use a nvarchar, so that way there isnt padding added if you don't meet the required string length. If so that might be better then constantly having to trim your string entry.

Comment: I just read up on the difference between nvarchar and nchar.  I will try implementing this field type and see if that helps.